# Selectors - do I always need to pass them a object?

Tags: ios, objective-c, selector

I am relative new to the usage of selectors so am playing around with it, I do not want to pass the selector any object, instead it´s purpose is only tell the class to update itself. I declare them as any other method, but only when it takes a parameter does it work, why is this?

```
//This works    
- (void) updateButtonImageState:(id)object;
// Calling it
[cell performSelector:@selector(updateButtonImageState:) withObject:@"object"];
```

-

```
//This crashes  
//Declaring the selector
- (void) updateButtonImageState;
// Calling it
[cell performSelector:@selector(updateButtonImageState:)];
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should not use colon at the end of selector name then:

```
[cell performSelector:@selector(updateButtonImageState)];
```

Comment: you must also declare the method without the colon and argument.

Comment: I think author already has done it - (void) updateButtonImageState;